# SWIFT: iPhone held “upwards” or is laying on a table

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, accelerometer, gyroscope

How do I have to use the accelerometer / gyroscope in Swift in order to find out if...

A) the iPhone is held just in front of the users face, i.e. it is held "upwards" or

B) the iPhone has been put for instance on a table, i.e. the display is facing up.

C) make an if statement for when it is put on a table or up in front of the users face.

Comment: Please share some code and let us know what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Chris I couldn't find any information on this online. I looked everywhere. I am seeing if anyone else has information on this... Do you have any?

Comment: My answer below should get you started...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIDeviceOrientation will return a value for which way a device is oriented:

```
   enum UIDeviceOrientation : Int {
        case Unknown
        case Portrait
        case PortraitUpsideDown
        case LandscapeLeft
        case LandscapeRight
        case FaceUp // <- THIS IS THE ONE THAT YOU ARE LOOKING FOR
        case FaceDown
    }
```

Without seeing your actual code or knowing exactly what you are trying to achieve it is impossible to give you more specific help than that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Chris! This is exactly what I was looking for!  ;-)